# namespace in C++ how to link?

Tags: c++, namespaces

My code has structure like this:

file1.cpp

```
namespace file1
{
  ...
  ...
}
int main()
{
  file2::func();
}
```

file2.cpp

```
namespace file2
{
     ...
     ...
}
```

How will I link file1.cpp with file2.cpp? It throws error that file1.cpp can't find `file2 namespace`. I tried adding `namespace file2{}` in file1.cpp, but still the same error.

Comment: Do you have a header for your file2.cpp? And did you include it in file1.cpp? (This is not a linker problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a header to declare things that are to be accessed from more than one source file:

```
// file2.h
#pragma once  // or a traditional include guard if you prefer

namespace file2 {
    void func();
}
```

Now include this from `file1.cpp` to enable the use of `file2::func` from there.

```
// file1.cpp
#include "file1.h"

// ...
```